# Partial View Name in Ajax response

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a controller that returns one of two partial view depending on condition.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ReviewCart(DepartmentProductViewModel model)
        {
            if(somecondition)
            {
               return PartialView("_View1", model);
            }


            return PartialView("_View2", model);
        }
```

In my View I have Two tabs one for _View1 and other for _View2 with div tags. Like 
**Tab 1**

```
<div id="shopping1">
                    @Html.Partial("_View1", Model)
                </div>
```

**Tab 2**

```
<div id="shopping2">
                        @Html.Partial("_View2", Model)
                    </div>
```

In my Ajax response I would like check the if controller is returning _View1 then I would like to

```
$('#shopping1').html(data);
```

and if controller is returning _View2 then I would like to

```
$('#shopping2').html(data);
```

Any idea how to achieve this in Ajax success call.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this example might help.

with help of [`jquery-ui tabs`](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax)

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
      beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
          ui.panel.html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        });
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action('ReviewCart','Controller')">Partial Content 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action('ReviewCart','Controller')">Partial Content 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">

  </div>
</div>
```

You may need pass a parameter to distinct two partial views from each other to render and change the action method itself accordingly.

E.g `Url.Action('ReviewCart','Controller',new { view=1 })`